# How could it be possible coercing the QCA_mm class objvet into a table?

Tags: r, flextable, truthtable

I have this table, produced as output from the truthTable() and minimize() functions of the package QCA

[image]

I am struggling with finding some method for coercing this QCA_min` object into a flextable (or I could even use another tool for creating a table). Important is fact the I would like to reproduce the equation with the sufficient statement:

```
M1: ~DEV + ~STB <-> ~SURV
```

Would you have any suggestions?

Thanks

```
library(QCA)
ttLCn <- truthTable(LC, ~SURV, sort.by = "incl, n", show.cases = TRUE)
pLCn <- minimize(ttLCn, include = "?", details = TRUE)
pLCn
```

Comment: The `dput` of the output is not reproducible because it doesn't write the `call=` in a format that you can copy/paste into R. Is there a simple example from the help pages of the document that you can use instead. So you want the equation in the table somehow? Or do you want two separate outputs?

Comment: Exactly, the equation above the column as it is in the pictures. Do you think that probably that fact that you cannot reproduce it is due to the fact that QCA package should be called?

Comment: Even with the library loaded, I get the error `Error in as.data.frame(df[[i]]) : object 'i' not found` when I copy/paste what you've provided into R. You can test it yourself in a fresh R session.

Comment: Updated! I have added an easier example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly pretty but you can see how the values are created by looking at the `QCA:::print.QCA_min` function. Here's a way to extract that infromation

```
capture_qca <- function(x) {
  m <- NULL
  suppressMessages(trace(admisc::prettyString, exit = function() m <<- returnValue(), print=TRUE))
  capture.output(QCA:::print.QCA_min(x))
  list(m, x$IC$incl.cov)
}
capture_qca(pLCn)
# [[1]]
# [1] "~DEV + ~STB <-> ~SURV"
# 
# [[2]]
#      inclS PRI covS covU                      cases
# ~DEV     1   1  0.8  0.3 GR,PT,ES; IT,RO; HU,PL; EE
# ~STB     1   1  0.7  0.2    GR,PT,ES; HU,PL; AU; DE
```

This returns a list with two elements. `capture_qca(pLCn)[[1]]` is the formula part and `capture_qca(pLCn)[[2]]` is a data.frame you can pass to flextable.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you think is there a way to print the footer that are not shown in the picture

Comment: Probably I got how to do ...just a question. I am able to find the function print.QCA_min..